# Creating a stable physics plane in AR

Tags: scenekit, arkit

For a project I am working on I am cresting a tower and placing it on the floor and enabling gravity.

First I create the floor with a static physics body, then generate a tower of many blocks and place them on the floor. I place them into the scenes root node by getting the position of the anchor node and enable gravity.

The problem is, as the plane moves slightly, the tower becomes very unstable and sometimes falls. I understand this is an issue in ARKit as it constantly refined the scenes positioning, however I just need a static floor so the blocks have a stable platform (it doesn’t have to even be seen).

Is there a way to solve this? Or any hacky solution (making the blocks stick to the floor, or turning off gravity before the scene moves, setting gravity on the platform, etc.?)

Comment: Are you using a plane node that scenekit adds when it detects a surface? If so then you could create a new duplicate node with the same parameters as the anchor and use this as the floor. This node will remain fixed even if scenekit updates its plane estimates.

Comment: No, I am adding it to the rootNode. It seems when I add the nodes which stack on top of each other, they start slowly slipping (even with friction on 1.0) and fall apart even though nothing is moving. Maybe it is a different problem then if the floor doesn’t move? When i put it in SceneKit it works just fine. The current work around I have is setting gravity to very little, although it’s slow it prevents them from moving enough from falling down. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you found a solution?